# Required text are not getting extracted

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am facing some problem extracting data using xpath of css selector from below html code.
I want to extract "XYZ" text and "xyz.com" text separately on 2 different variables.
I tried using css selector like below but it extracted all the text XYZ and xyz.com
    response.css('p>b[id="name"],

```
<p>
    <b id="name">Name</b>
    <i class="abc">
        <a href="">XYX</a>
    </i>
</p>

<p>
    <b id="email">Email</b>
    <i class="abc">
        <a href="">XYX.com</a>
    </i>
</p>
```

Is there any way I can extract and store xyz and xyz.com in separate variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with XPath:

```
name = response.xpath('//p[b[@id="name"]]/i/a/text()').extract_first()
email = response.xpath('//p[b[@id="email"]]/i/a/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: @PradeepMishra If you received working answer, please accept it.

Comment: how can we store the value of this tag<span class="sdr-full-width">हिन्दी</span> that is "हिन्दी" I tried to extract but getting \u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940 unicode characters.
please help